# Quarkus CXF WSDL FileNotFound Exception running it on AKS

Tags: cxf, quarkus, azure-aks

Works as it should locally, but not on the server. This is the error log:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/main/resources/checkVatService.wsdl (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:150)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:861)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 42 more
```

The app was built using Azure DevOps and it is deployed on Azure Kubernetes Service.

The WSDL file is under src/main/resources directory... and the configuration in application.properties is as follow:

```
quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.includes = *.wsdl
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: FileNotFoundException meaning that file is not at the location, and it is in azure kubernetes service, so I would suggest to load it from jar and from memory, reaching to file in kubernetes environment can generate this kind of exceptions.

Comment: The above stack trace is a result of doing what? Calling some specific (which?) Maven goal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue, specifying the wsdl paths on the properties files:

```
# CXF
quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.stuff.includes = wsdl/stuff.wsdl
quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.stuff.wsdl-location = classpath:wsdl/stuff.wsdl

quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.otherStuff.includes = wsdl/otherStuff.wsdl
quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java..wsdl-location = classpath:wsdl/otherStuff.wsdl
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find any clear documentation about this.