# Quarkus wsdl file URL in native image

Tags: maven, native, quarkus

I have a quarkus lambda that i compile with
`mvn clean install`
and then deploy locally with
`awslocal lambda create-function --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --function-name name --runtime java17 --handler io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest --role arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/insignificant --timeout 30 --zip-file fileb://../src/test/target/function.zip`

the function uses the

`quarkus.native.resources.includes = wsdl/**,xsd/**,*.properties,wsdl/*.*`

in the application.properties to include some files
if I compile with

`mvn clean install -Dnative`

it can no longer find the files in the lambda.

I searched the whole filesystem from the inside and coudn't find the wsdl file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301174/175554 may help